# Determining which action called a method

Tags: objective-c

I have a button that is linked to two actions touchDown and touchUpInside.
Both these actions call the same method.
What I need to know is which action called the method, so I can execute different instructions for when the button was pressed and released inside the same method.

I have tried looking at the buttons state property, but it doesn't seem to change, or the touchDown action is firing the event before the button's state changes and the touchUpInside action is firing it after the buttons state has changed back, resulting in the state appearing not to change.

Answer (score 0):

Determining which event called the method is not possible in IOS. But, as per your requirement, first TouchDown event will call the method and then only the TouchUpInside event will call the method. Based on this order of the events firing you can able to manage the code inside the method is possible.

Comment: I don't think that is going to work. If the user drags their finger out before lifting then the touchUpInside wont fire and the next event I get will be a touchDown but I will think it is a touchUpInside. If I add more actions to catch the drag outside and other such things, I run the risk of getting multiple actions fired for the same user action of lifting their finger.